# What am I missing to unlock Lucarionite from Contest spectacular?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

If you win all the contest ranks and get first place vs. Lilia and Ali, you get Lucario's Mega Evolution stone, Lucarionite. That's what I've read on everything about the contest - it says if you beat master rank 5 times you unlock it.

I've beat it way more than that. I've gotten to the Master Rank and I've come 1st over 10 times. At first it was hard but now it's just boring, I thought you only had to beat it 5 times and you would go against Ali and Lilia but nothings happening.

I've got 4 Comet Shards, more berries than needed and I've maxed out the star with Pokeblocks, what am I meant to do now?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: if you win all the contest ranks and get first place vs. Lilia and Ali, you get Lucario's Mega Evolution stone, Lucarionite.  That's what it says on everything about the contest and it says if you beat master rank 5 times and I've beat it way more than that

Comment: Plus I've played the game before and it didn't take this many wins

Comment: @Alex - I've added in your comments and retitled the question to be more appropriate to what it is you're actually trying to do. It always helps to be as clear as possible, we can't read your mind :)

Answer (score 2):

To face off against Lisia in a Contest Spectacular, you first have to win all five Master categories, then participate in any Master level contest.

Comment: That's probably the important distinction: Beat it in all five **categories**, not just beat it 5 times (in the same category or couple of categories).

Comment: Is it possible to do all categories with the cosplay pikachu?